# Using Validation Set in GridSearchCV/RandomizedCV or not?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

As I know, cross validation (in GridSearchCV/RandomizedSearchCV) will split data into folds, in which each fold acts as a validataion set one time.
But one recommendation from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#model-selection-development-and-evaluation):

> Model selection by evaluating various parameter settings can be seen as a way to use the labeled data to “train” the parameters of the grid.
> When evaluating the resulting model it is important to do it on held-out samples that were not seen during the grid search process: it is recommended to split the data into a development set (to be fed to the GridSearchCV instance) and an evaluation set to compute performance metrics.
> This can be done by using the train_test_split utility function.

So we may use "train_test_split" to split original data to train data and valid data

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25)
```

And using X_train,y_train in fit GridSearchCV/RandomizedSearchCV, and X_val, y_val for eval_set  in fit_params.

Is It really useful?

We apply split orginal data twice( SearchCV and train_test_split) --> necessary?

Data apply in SearchCV is less (X vs X_train) --> less accuracy in training?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: got it. Thanks @desertnaut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation here refers to evaluation set as the test set. Therefore you should use `train_test_split` to split your data into a train set and a test set.

This is useful to perform this `train_test_split` as you will then be able to validate the result of your model using the test set that contains unseen data.

The train set will be use during the `GridSearchCV` to find the best parameter for your model. As explained in the documentation you can use `cv` parameter to train your model using `n-1` fold and validate it with `1` fold.

I would recommend to use cross validation set during `GridSearchCV` instead of having a fix validation set as this will give you a better indication on how your model perform on unseen data.